# How to install wordpress on website using direct admin

Tags: php, wordpress, installation, directadmin

I'm a complete noob with wordpress and i'm trying to install it on my server.

I'm following the instructions on [this site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) but when I get to [step 5](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Step_5:_Run_the_Install_Script) and I go to the http://example.com/direct-admin/install.php I get this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

In my folder 'example.com', located in the 'domains' folder, I started with only stats and logs folders. The first time I added the Wordpress files in the 'example.com' folder.

I tried adding a public_html folder and putting the Wordpress files in the public_html folder but that didn't work either.

How can I install wordpress on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having trouble setting up a wordpress installation and you're getting 404 errors or "apache is function normally" then it's possible that your DNS/server settings aren't correct, this was my error.

First try creating a .html file with a simple text editor by copying the html markup below into a new file and then save it as index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading<h1/>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
</code></pre>
```

And upload that to your server.

If you're still having errors you know it's not the wordpress installation that causes these but it's your server settings.

You should:

- check if you are putting it in the right folder (like f.e. public_html)
- make sure that your DNS configuration is correct

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121056/how-to-make-a-website-run-the-index-html-file) for more information on how to setup your server to view a simple .html file.

Answer (score 1):

What server are you using? There are several ways of installing WordPress, I would strongly recommend using the [WordPress CLI](https://wp-cli.org/#installing) to install WordPress. All you have to do is follow these steps:

1. Download the WordPress CLI using [these five steps](https://wp-cli.org/#installing).
2. Use now the CLI to download WordPress:

   `$ wp core download`
3. Create the wp-config.php file

   `$ wp core config --dbname="your_db_name" --dbuser="your_db_user" --dbpass="your_db_password"`

And then you can put your website URL in your browser and continue following the wizard, WordPress will ask you what site name, username and password do you want to use.

Comment: I know this is technically a correct answer, but if someone is a novice when just trying to install WordPress, I think CLI might be a bit too much, especially when WP offers a simple five minute install - and they are having trouble with that.

Comment: I'm not an admin, just a user so I believe I don't have acces to commands, I think.

Comment: Ok, I found out there was a problem with the server, when I type in my normal example.com webadress it shows "Apache is functioning normally" which apparently means there is a problem with my dns or something